# Extended IdentityServer4 Asp.NetCore redirects to login page

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a strange situation:

In my solution I have IdentityServer4 and a MVC client.

I extended User storage and in my MVC client Startup class:

```
services.AddIdentity<KbcIdentityUser, KbcIdentityRole>(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                    })
                .AddUserStore<IdentityUserStore>().AddRoleStore<IdentityRoleStore>()                    
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<KbcIdentityDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Whenever I add this code to Startup file, by calling any authorized MVC client controller, it goes to local login page (which does not exist). Instead of redirecting to IdentityServer login page.

If I remove this code it redirects correctly.

Any Idea?

Using following:

- .NetCore v2.2
- Asp.NetCore v2.2
- Microsoft.AaspnetCore.Identity v2.2.0

Comment: At a guess the Identity registration helper is overriding the IDS4 config. Are you sure you need it in the client app?

Comment: Can you post all the code in your Startup.cs file? It’s hard to get a look into what’s happening without understanding the context.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not added the IdentityServer4 services and middleware. Have you added the following middleware

```
 app.UseIdentityServer();
```

And IdentityServer4 services?

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
```